# How to make button keyboard(A-Z) bigger while touching like iphone keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uikeyboard

I am doing a customized keyboard. How to make those keyboard of letter button(A-Z) bigger while touching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the button's events. There're `UIControlEventTouchDown`, `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and some others. You should assign `IBActions` to those events.

But if you have many buttons you'd better subclass UIButton and override it's `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:` and `touchesEnded:` messages.

In these messages resize your button's frame according to your needs (you could even change it's background image or text size). But make sure superview of your buttons doesn't have `Clips Subviews` attribute set.